# Windows 7 Update is available - but not displayed

Tags: windows-7, updates

Today a yet unknown issue occurred to me with Windows 7 Updates.
It is different from questions I found researching for this topic. I didn't have a problem finding, downloading or installing the update.
I don't have an english system so I don't know the exact wording of the window I describe. I'll explain how to get there.

- The updater said there is an update available (the bubble and icon appeared in the tray bar).
- The Windows Update page in the Control Panel showed the download and now shows the update is downloaded.
- Control Panel's Windows Update page shows `1 important Update is available`.
- Clicking on this text opens a window `Chose updates to be installed` where updates are shown with name and size and one can select what to install and what to skip.
- This window has one vertical tab saying `Important (1)` - there must be one important update.
- Now the strange part: This tab is selected but the list doesn't show an update.

I wonder what's happening and how can I fix it?

I opened this window multiple times and rebootet the PC. No change.

## Edit - What it is

Finally I decided to install this update.
For those who want to know what it is. The updates history says at this day KB915597 - Windows Defender - was installed. There are 4 of these KB in my history, each with a different version number. Three of them already were installed on other days.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to see it, or do you just need to install it?

Right now all I'm seeing in that list is the latest Defender definitions, KB915597.

By default, important updates will already be checked in that panel, so just hitting 'Install Updates' ought to do it. I'd at least just try that & see what happens - It shouldn't need a restart & should take only 5 - 10s. If it goes green, you did it & can check back next week to see if the issue was a one-off or needs further investigation.

Comment: Really need ... well let's say yes I do like to see what will be installed and this strangely empty list makes me hesitate to just install that. According to my history KB915597 already was installed on this machine.

Comment: Maybe try "Restore Hidden Updates" from the left of the main CP in case that will give it a kick... I can't see anything newer than the definitions update I mentioned above.